# How to fix invalid index to scalar variable in a function

Tags: python

Im trying to make a function with different differential approaches. Euler forward and backward. I did them with 2 separate for loops but I want to gather them one single function.

```
Ca0 = 1
t = 10 
Nt= 11 
k = 0.1 
deltat = t/Nt
c = np.zeros(Nt)
c[-1] = Ca0
def differential(c, method = 'backwards'):
if method == 'euler':
    euler = []
    for t in range(0, Nt):
        c[t] = c[t-1] - c[t-1] * k * deltat
        euler.append(c[t])
    #so i get initial value (1) in the list
    euler.insert(0, 1)
elif method == 'backwards':
    backwards = []
    for t in range(0, Nt):
        c[t] = c[t-1] * (1/(1+(k*deltat)))
        backwards.append(c[t])
    #so i get initial value (1) in the list
    backwards.insert(0, 1)

print (differential(c[-1], method = 'euler'))
```

But it says IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

While this is working.

```
for t in range(0, Nt):
   c[t] = c[t-1] - c[t-1] * k * deltat
   euler.append(c[t])
euler.insert(0, 1)
#backwards differential equation
c_b = np.zeros(Nt)
c_b[-1] = Ca0
backwards = []
for t in range(0, Nt):
    c_b[t] = c_b[t-1] * (1/(1+(k*deltat)))
    backwards.append(c_b[t])
backwards.insert(0, 1)
```

I would like to graphically compare two different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mixup between your `c` variable inside the differential function and your `c` variable outside : inside, `c` is in fact 1 (it is assigned from your outside `c[-1]`).

Another problem is your function returns nothing, thus your print displays simply `None`. It should return either `euler` or `backward` i suppose.

In python 3 solving both these problems seem to be enough. In python 2 be careful the result of `t/Nt` (`10/11`) is in fact `0`.

Putting it all together you have something in these lines :

```py
Ca0 = 1
t = 10 
Nt= 11 
k = 0.1 
deltat = t/Nt
c = np.zeros(Nt)
c[-1] = Ca0
def differential(c, method = 'backwards'):
    if method == 'euler':
        euler = []
        for t in range(0, Nt):
            c[t] = c[t-1] - c[t-1] * k * deltat
            euler.append(c[t])
        #so i get initial value (1) in the list
        euler.insert(0, 1)
        return euler
    elif method == 'backwards':
        backwards = []
        for t in range(0, Nt):
            c[t] = c[t-1] * (1/(1+(k*deltat)))
            backwards.append(c[t])
        #so i get initial value (1) in the list
        backwards.insert(0, 1)
        return backwards

print (differential(c, method = 'euler'))
```

Comment: If I try to transfer it inside i says "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: Sorry, ill post a fixed version for clarity.